# SQL looking up values on three joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, lookup-tables

I have a table structure where there are `CARS` going between `BUILDINGS` that are built on `PLOTS`:

**CARS**

```
CAR_ID  |  ORIGIN  |   DESTINATION
----------------------------------
   1    |    A     |       C
   2    |    B     |       A
   3    |    A     |       B
```

**BUILDINGS**

```
BUILD_ID  |   PLOT
------------------
   A      |    2
   B      |    1
   C      |    3
```

**PLOTS**

```
PLOT_ID  |  COORD
------------------------
  1      |  "39.9,-75.5"
  2      |  "38.3,-74.7"
  3      |  "37.8,-76.1"
```

I'm trying to build a query that would show for each `CAR`, the `PLOT` coordinates of the origin and destination `BUILDING`s, like this:

```
 CAR_ID   |   ORIGIN_COORD   |   DEST_COORD
-------------------------------------------
  1       |   "38.3,-74.7"   | "37.8,-76.1"
  2       |   "39.9,-75.5"   | "38.3,-74.7"
  3       |   "39.9,-75.5"   | "39.9,-75.5"
```

This is what I tried but I don't think I'm approaching this right.

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT BUILD_ID, PLOT, COORD FROM BUILDINGS
    INNER JOIN PLOTS ON PLOT = PLOT_ID) X
RIGHT JOIN CARS C
ON C.ORIGIN = X.BUILD_ID
```

Could someone please help me understand how to lookup/join for multiple columns (`ORIGIN` and `DEST`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

below is my first thought:

```
select c.car_id,p1.coord as origin_coord, p2.coord as dest_coord
from cars as c
join buildings as b1 on b1.build_id=c.origin
join buildings as b2 on b2.build_id=c.destination
join plots as p1 on p1.plot_id=b1.plot
join plots as p2 on p2.plot_id=b2.plot
```

Comment: so I need to join twice? is there any other possible way? if the tables are big, won't it affect performance?

Comment: @greener, one way or another you're going to need to know what plots two buildings are on. That implies two joins. If you have an index set up on buildings.build_id, I think you'll be fine. Also, remember that sql is a declarative language: the optimizer is responsible for finding the lowest cost execution path. I wouldn't worry about performance until you notice the optimizer failing the job.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`SELECT C.car_id, po.coord as origin_coord, pd.cooord as dest_coord 
FROM Cars as C
JOIN Buildings as o
  on c.origin = o.build_id
JOIN Buildings as d
  on c.destination = d.build_id
JOIN Plots as po
  on po.plot_id = o.plot
JOIN Plots as pd
  on pd.plot_id = d.plot
ORDER BY C.car_id`

Answer (score 1):

I created something like this:

```
SELECT A.CAR_ID, B2.COORD AS ORIGIN, C2.COORD AS DESTINATION
FROM CARS AS A
LEFT JOIN BUILDINGS AS B
ON A.ORIGIN = B.BUILD_ID
LEFT JOIN PLOTS AS B2
ON B.PLOT = B2.PLOT_ID
LEFT JOIN BUILDINGS AS C
ON A.DESTINATION = C.BUILD_ID
LEFT JOIN PLOTS AS C2
ON C.PLOT = C2.PLOT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the answers are already here. I add mine here.

```
select c.car_id, 
p1.coord as OriginCoord,
p2.coord as DestinationCoord
from cars as c
    left outer join buildings as b1
        on c.origin = b1.build_id
    left outer join buildings as b2 
        on c.destination = b2.build_id
    left outer join plots as p1
        on b1.plot = p1.plot_id
    left outer join plots as p2
        on b2.plot = p2.plot_id
order by c.car_id
```